# What are the most dangerous concepts in the practice of data analysis?

Tags: fallacy

There are a few things that are heavily used in the practice of statistics, data analysis, etc. and that form the common canon of education, yet everybody knows they are not exactly true, useful, well-behaved, or empirically supported.

So here is the question: Which is the single worst idea still actively propagated?

Please make it one suggestion per post.